# object array assignment problem

Tags: java, arrays, object, variable-assignment

I have a problem where each element of my array seem to be reassigned.

```
class Car {
    private static int nom = 0;
    private static String whee = "";
    public void setCar(int r, String s) {
        this.nom = r;
        this.whee = s;
    }
}

class Rawr {
    private Car[] jar = new Car[3];

    public Mar() {
        jar[0] = new Car();
        jar[1] = new Car();
        jar[2] = new Car();
        jar[0].setCar(2, "yar");
        jar[1].setCar(3, "tar");
        jar[2].setCar(4, "sars");
    }
}
```

If I printed it like `jar[0].nom + jar[0].whee + jar[1].nom + jar[2].whee + jar[3].whee`, the output would be

```
4 sars 4 sars sars
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To the right when you were asking your question there was this handy **How to Format** box. Worth a read, as is [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. When you're writing your questino, there's a preview of how it will look underneath the text box.

Answer (score 6):

It's because your variables are static i.e. they belong to the class, rather than to an instance. Take a look at [Java Tutorials | Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for more information about what this means.

You should remove the `static` keyword, so that they become instance variables.

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
private static int nom = 0;
private static String whee = "";
```

to

```
private int nom = 0;
private String whee = "";
```

`static` means the variable is shared by all instances. (The fact you can use `this` to refer to static variables is a Java oddity.)

Comment: As a rule, don't set static fields in a constructor.  Try making the fields `final`. This can help you avoid many mistakes.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, **very** good rule. But in this case, I think he doesn't want them to be statics anyway, so...

Comment: Whenever I have seen static fields set in a constructor it has been the source of a bug or confusion. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your nom and whee fields are static. This means that they are tied to the class, and not to the object (instance) of the class.

Thus, when you assign a new value to this.nom, in reality, you assign a the value to Car.nom. The compiler allows referring to static variables through an object, but it's very bad practice. You should always refer to static fields by their class : Car.nom, Car.whee. This makes it clear that the nom and whee are static, and thus shared by all instances of the class. In this case, these fields should not be static : each Car instance has its own name and whee (whatever it might be).

Answer (score 0):

A better way to structure your code is as follows.

```
class Car {
    private final int nom;
    private final String whee;
    public Car(int nom, String whee) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.whee = whee;
    }
    public String toString() { return num + " " + whee; }
}

class Rawr {
    private final Car[] jar = {new Car(2, "yar"), new Car(3, "tar"), new Car(4, "sars")};
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(jar);
    }
}
```